# Qt + xapian library

Tags: qt, xapian

I'm trying to use Xapian library in my Qt-project.
I've just added header:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <xapian.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);   

    return a.exec();
}
```

And there are already some mistakes here:

```
/usr/local/include/xapian/keymaker.h:64: error: a template-id may not appear in 
a using-declaration
64: std::vector<std::pair<Xapian::valueno, bool> > slots;
```

and this one as well:

```
/usr/local/include/xapian/keymaker.h:77: error: expected primary-expression 
before ‘.’ token
77: slots.push_back(std::make_pair(slot, reverse));
```

I don't know what does it mean. But I guess I should add something into my pro-file. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you run into is that Xapian uses "slots" as identifier, but "slots" is also a define in Qt:

From qobjectdefs.h

```
# if defined(QT_NO_KEYWORDS)
#  define QT_NO_EMIT
# else
#   define slots
#   define signals protected
# endif
```

As you include QApplication (and thus qobjectdefs.h) before xapian.h, the preprocessor deletes all occurrences of "slots" from xapian.h.
To avoid this problem, build your project with -DQT_NO_KEYWORDS.
You then have to use "Q_SLOTS" and "Q_SIGNALS" instead of "signals" and "slots" in your Qt Code (which is good practice anyway).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is much better than mine. I've just replaced "slots" to "slots1" in keymaker.h. Maybe later I'll use your suggestion.